# Animate Expand/Collapse text wrapper in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

I'm new to react-native dev, I want to have a simple expand/slide height effect after pressing a button, I tried following the docs but Animation is react-native is utterly ridiculous imho.

My code is pretty simple, the View I want to animate is the View wrapper around the text with props.item.body after clicking onIsExpanded callback.
This is the view:

```
const [ isExpanded, setIsExpanded ] = useState(false);
    const [ maxHeight, setMaxHeight ] = useState(null);
    const [ minHeight, setMinHeight ] = useState(null);
    const [ animation, setAnimation ] = useState(new Animated.Value());
   

    const toggleIsExpanded = () => 
    {
        setIsExpanded(!isExpanded);
    };


<View style={{ width:'100%', flexDirection:'column', position:'relative',}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ width:'100%', height:50}} onPress={ toggleIsExpanded }>
                        <EntypoIcon name="chevron-small-down" style={{ color:'rgb(68,68,68)', fontSize:20 }}/>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    {//How to expand/collapse this?}
                    <View style={{ width:'100%', padding:10 }}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize:14, color:'rgb(68,68,68)' }}>{ props.item.body }</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time `Animated` works well in scenario's where width, opacity, etc are values known upfront. In this case however the height of the `Text` completely depends the length of the body, and that is value that is hard to calculate.

From my experience `LayoutAnimation` works best in these scenarios, you just indicate right before your set state that an animation will happen after the state change. `LayoutAnimation` figures out the rest.

Check the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutanimation) for more information.

To update your code:

```
    const defaultAnimation = {
      duration: 200,
      create: {
        duration: 200,
        type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
        property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity,
      },
      update: {
        type: LayoutAnimation.Types.easeInEaseOut,
      },
    };


    const [ isExpanded, setIsExpanded ] = useState(false);
    const [ maxHeight, setMaxHeight ] = useState(null);
    const [ minHeight, setMinHeight ] = useState(null);
   

    const toggleIsExpanded = () => 
    {
        // This will make sure an animation is trigger after toggling
        LayoutAnimation.configureNext(defaultAnimation);
        setIsExpanded(prev => !prev);
    };

    return (
       <View style={{ width:'100%', flexDirection:'column', position:'relative',}}>
           <TouchableOpacity style={{ width:'100%', height:50}} onPress={ toggleIsExpanded }>
               <EntypoIcon name="chevron-small-down" style={{ color:'rgb(68,68,68)', fontSize:20 }}/>
           </TouchableOpacity>
           {//How to expand/collapse this?}
           {!!expanded && (
           <View style={{ width:'100%', padding:10 }}>
               <Text style={{ fontSize:14, color:'rgb(68,68,68)' }}>{ props.item.body }</Text>
           </View>)}
       </View>
    );
```